# Adding Non Linear Lines to xyplot (lattice)

Tags: r, plot, lattice

Dataset:

```
Distance <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,15 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,15, 15 ,15, 15 ,15 ,15 ,15,15 ,15 ,20, 20 ,20, 20 ,20, 20 ,20, 20 ,20 ,20 ,20 ,20 ,20 ,20, 20 ,20, 20 ,20, 20 ,20, 20)
CHeight <- c(400,300,200,0,-200,-400,-600,-800,-1000,-1000,-1200,-1220,-1300 ,-1400,-1400,-1500,-1600,-1700,-1700,-1800,-1900,400,200,0,-200,-400,-600,-800,-1000,-1200,-1200,-1400,-1600,-1600,-1800,-2000,-2000,-2200,-2200,-2400,-2600,-2800,-3000,400,200,0,-200,-300,-400,-500,-600,-700,-800,-900,-1000,-1100,-1200,-1200,-1400,-1600,-1800,-1800,-2000,-2200,-2400,-2400,-2600,-2800,-3000,400,200,0,-200,-400,-600,-800,-1000,-1200,-1400,-1600,-1600,-1800,-2000,-2200,-2400,-2400,-2600,-2800,-3000,1000,800,600,400,200,0,-200,-400,-600,-800,-1000,-1200,-1400,-1600,-1800,-2000,-2200,-2400,-2600,-2800,-3000)
Value <- c(163301.080, 269704.110 ,334570.550, 409536.530, 433021.260 ,418962.060, 349554.460, 253987.570,124461.710, 140750.480  ,52612.790 , 54286.427  ,26150.025  ,14631.210  ,15780.244 ,  8053.618, 4402.581,   2251.137  , 2743.511 ,  1707.508 ,  1246.894 ,176232.060 ,270797.240 ,323096.710,333401.080, 311949.900 ,272821.770 ,189571.850 ,114263.560  ,51939.070  ,62578.665  ,36905.438,  22625.515,  22940.591  ,14576.295  , 9686.653 , 10344.214  , 6912.779  , 7092.919   ,5366.797, 4058.492,   3270.734  , 2528.644  ,89311.555 ,116698.175 ,143588.620 ,139203.190, 145399.445, 145635.715, 134671.110 ,128931.160 ,119734.835 ,108708.815 , 90221.955  ,81692.585 , 64882.275,58215.735,  60443.190  ,44690.690 , 33224.152 , 24140.272 , 24913.280  ,19082.689  ,13920.669, 11074.718,  10015.653   ,8743.850  , 7516.880 ,  6377.743 , 36888.842  ,43088.720  ,47904.490, 51298.710,  51120.887  ,47687.488  ,42238.912 , 38563.007 , 33902.918  ,28565.303  ,23700.862,24818.393,  21620.129 , 17816.061  ,15377.097 , 12992.321  ,12985.911  ,11177.941   ,9536.621,8357.279,  13052.178 , 14325.789  ,15120.314 , 16227.575  ,17226.307  ,18557.270  ,18680.326, 18844.544,  18205.607,  17770.311  ,16605.438 , 16062.309  ,14785.654  ,14324.493  ,13373.627,12135.392,  10632.699,   9155.762  , 8240.951,   6934.240  , 6475.927)
Factor1 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
Factor2 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
Factor3 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)

Frame=data.frame(Distance, CHeight, Value, Factor1, Factor2, Factor3)
```

I have a function

```
mainfunction<-function(CHeight,Distance,a,b,f,g,k){
  (a * exp(-((Height + b)/2 * g)^2) - (k * Distance)) + a * 
   exp(-((CHeight + b)/(2 * g + f * Distance))^2) * (1 - exp(-k * Distance))
}
```

And I have an `xyplot` like:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Value ~ CHeight | Distance*Factor1, 
       data=Frame[Frame$Factor2==1 & Frame$Factor3==1,])
```

Now I would like to put some lines on the matrix scatterplot

```
lines(x, mainfunction(x,10,40000,0,1/500,1/500,0))
```

Which doesn't work, so any help regarding that would be great. But in a perfect world I would like to be able to put in a separate sequence. To make the value for y a sequence as well.

So something like

```
Distance <- seq(0,20,5)
```

So in short I essentially want to be able to change the value of parameters in the function and visually see how they impact the fit of the data via lines on a scatterplot matrix.

Comment: Are you set on using lattice (please add the tag if that's the case)? Also, please make your example reproducible (i.e., provide an example of `data`, see [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059)).

Comment: Changed everything, I think it's reproducible now.

Comment: It's better now. Are you sure you don't want to fit your function to the data? Unfortunately I can't help you with lattice, because I'm mainly a ggplot2 user.

Comment: not too fussed with lattice or ggplot2, just want something that can graph the plots and lines at this stage for fitting later on, sorry about the sloppyness earlier,it's been a long day.
Regards

Comment: Produce a grid of `Distance` and `CHeight` values (`expand.grid` is useful here). Evaluate your function for these values. Put everything in a data.frame and plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in `mainfunction`, you have a `Height` instead of `CHeight`.

`lines` won't work in `lattice`.  This will plot them, using `panel.lines`:

```
    xyplot(Value ~ CHeight | Distance*Factor1, 
           data=Frame[Frame$Factor2==1 & Frame$Factor3==1,]
    ,panel=function(x,y,...){
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
         panel.lines(x, mainfunction(x,10,40000,0,1/500,1/500,0))
})
```

I guess then you need to make them line up.

UPDATE:

If I understand your comment, you would like the line drawn in each panel to use the appropriate value for `Distance` rather than a fixed value of 10.  One way is to use the `subscripts` argument to the `panel` function, which gives the row numbers of the original data that are used in each panel. With that, you can look up the value of `Distance` for those rows and use in `mainfunction`.  For example:

```
    xyplot(Value ~ CHeight | Distance*Factor1, 
           data=Frame[Frame$Factor2==1 & Frame$Factor3==1,]
    ,panel=function(x,y,subscripts,...){
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
         D =Frame[Frame$Factor2==1 & Frame$Factor3==1,]$Distance[subscripts[1]]
        panel.text(0,0,D) #diagnostic to show D for each panel
         panel.lines(x, mainfunction(x,D,40000,0,1/500,1/500,0))
})
```

Here I set `D` to the value of `Distance` for the current subset and use that in `mainfunction`.  I also printed it out just to show it is different in each panel.  The curves all look the same to me, but if for example you set `k` to 10, you get some differences.

Comment: Thank you so much, would you happen to know if there's a way i could make the lines for the Distance component show up automatically?

So i can compare the matrix of scatter plots to my function across distance and height at the same time?